# Getting "Null Object Reference" While Trying Encapsulation

Tags: java, android, encapsulation

It's probably stupidly simple, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I'm trying to create a demo for showcasing Encapsulation.

Encapsulation.class:

```
public class Encapsulation {
// 'numberOfEggs' is an instance variable
// it was made 'private', because we do NOT want it to be directly accessed by other classes
// being 'private' also means that only code within the class can read or write its value
private int numberOfEggs = 10;

// getter
public int getNumberOfEggs() {
    return numberOfEggs;
}

// setter
public void setNumberOfEggs(int numberOfEggs) {
    if (numberOfEggs > 0) {
        // we used the 'this' keyword to differentiate between the method parameter 'currentNumberOfEggs' and
        //  the instance variable 'currentNumberOfEggs'
        this.numberOfEggs = numberOfEggs;
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView defaultNumberOfEggs;
Encapsulation encapsulation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    defaultNumberOfEggs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.default_number_of_eggs);
    defaultNumberOfEggs.setText(encapsulation.getNumberOfEggs());
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.vladp.studyandroid1.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/default_number_of_eggs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I get a "null object reference" error, when starting the app and setting the text via `defaultNumberOfEggs.setText(encapsulation.getNumberOfEggs());`, which should display "10" (without the quotation marks).

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: You never instantiated the class `Encapsulation`.

Comment: You need to initiate `encapsulation`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onCreate` method, add a first line as

```
encapsulation = new Encapsulation();
```

Comment: Of course it was stupidly simple :P Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize your `encapsulation` object. By default, it points to null.

So you should either define it on class level:

`Encapsulation encapsulation = new Encapsulation();`

Or in constructor:

```
MainActivity() {
    encapsulation = new Encapsulation();
}
```

Or inside `onCreate` method after calling super:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    encapsulation = new Encapsulation();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ....
}
```

Comment: Also correct. I checked the above answer as correct, just because I saw it first, but yours is on-point, as well. Thank you!